# Loading jQuery with plugins in a React component and browserify bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, reactjs

I have checked for this problem on every search engine and IRC room I could think of, and also tried to understand what is happening with the module loading code in jQuery and the plugin I want to use (DataTables). There are some links [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/434) and [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/112712169830/making-your-jquery-plugin-work-better-with-npm) that explain how this is supposed to work, but there are no examples and I can't get it.

Here's the code from the top/bottom of the jQuery-DataTables plugin:

```
(/** @lends <global> */function( window, document, undefined ) {

(function( factory ) {
    "use strict";

    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // Define as an AMD module if possible
        define( 'datatables', ['jquery'], factory );
    }
    else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
        // Node/CommonJS
        module.exports = factory( require( 'jquery' ) );
    }
    else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable ) {
        // Define using browser globals otherwise
        // Prevent multiple instantiations if the script is loaded twice
        factory( jQuery );
    }
}
(/** @lends <global> */function( $ ) {

    // plugin code...

    return $.fn.dataTable;
}));

}(window, document));
```

And in my React component:

```
var React = require('react');
var $ = require('jquery');
var dataTable = require('datatables');
var Table = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount () {
    var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    var table = $(node).DataTable({
      //options
    });
    console.log(table); // to see what the table is
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
module.exports = Table;
```

I've also tried it another way with:

```
var table = $.fn.dataTable.Api(node)
```

which also doesn't work. The first way gets me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTable' of null`, and the second just gets me an `undefined`.

There are also a bunch of SO questions about similar situations (not enough reputation to post more links, sorry), but nobody has given an answer with a working example yet. Can anyone explain what the module loader code is doing so we can understand how to get this working, or, even better, a working example?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without a module loader?

Answer (score 0):

The module loader code is defining the module in something called UMD, which means Universal Module Definition. It's a way to expose a module that is module system agnostic. The code checks if it's used inside CommonJS, AMD or globals, and hooks into the one you're using.

I can't really tell what's going on here, but one thing I see is that you're requiring `jquery/dist/jquery` whereas the plugin is just requiring `jquery`. This means that you'll end up with two different jQuery versions in your bundle, and the plugin is registered on the jQuery that you're not using. You should just require `jquery` like the plugin does, and then run minification on your bundle as a build step.

Comment: Ah you're right, but I tried many, many things and `jquery/dist/jquery` was simply the one that I ended up copying here. I'll change that back to `jquery` as the result is exactly the same..